# need help with a little bit of code

Tags: template, search, html

I have installed the algolia search function and it performs as it should however I have been left puzzled by how the search bar doesn't sit right.

[image]

As you can see the html has thrown up an extra piece of code which is hidden normally. This is the css from the algolia for the searchbox:

```
/**
 * Search Box
*/
#algolia-searchbox{
  margin: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.clear-cross {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background: url("clear-cross.svg") no-repeat center center / contain;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}

#algolia-searchbox .clear-query-autocomplete {
  top: 13px;
  right: 12px;
}

#algolia_instant_selector .clear-query-instant {
  right: 12px;
  top: 10px;
}

.cross-wrapper .clear-refinement {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
 }

#algolia-autocomplete-container .aa-suggestions svg.algolia-glass-suggestion.magnifying-glass {
    position: absolute;
    right: auto;
    left: 5px;
    top: 7px;
    fill: #A6A6A6;
    stroke: #A6A6A6;
}

#algolia-searchbox .magnifying-glass {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  top: 10px;
  background: url("magnifying-glass.svg") no-repeat center right / 20px;
}

#algolia-searchbox .algolia-search-input {
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
}

#algolia-searchbox .algolia-search-input:focus:not([value=""]) {
  background: transparent;
}


#algolia-searchbox .algolia-search-input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: solid 1px #008000;
}
```

This is the HTML for the search bar.

```
if ($config->isDefaultSelector()): ?>
    <form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">
        <div id="algolia-searchbox">
            <label for="search"><?php echo $this->__('Search:') ?></label>
            <input id="search" type="text" name="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getQueryParamName() ?>" class="input-text algolia-search-input" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" placeholder="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>" />
            <span class="clear-cross clear-query-autocomplete"></span>
            <span id="algolia-glass" class="magnifying-glass" width="24" height="24"></span>
        </div>
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I haven't got a clue what file I need to edit as it's not showing up when I inspect the area.

Anyone have a clue as to what I would need to do as algolia forums don't even bother to help you.

Comment: pass site URL to check

Comment: [link]https://ashtondisc.co.uk/

Answer (score 2):

Update below CSS and clear cache

```
#algolia-searchbox{
   float:right;
}
#algolia-searchbox label{
   float:left;
   margin-right:10px;
   line-height:30px;
}
#algolia-autocomplete-tt.algolia-autocomplete{
   width:auto;
}
#algolia-searchbox .magnifying-glass{
   top:5px; 
   right:5px;
}
.main-container{
   z-index:5;
}
```

If using less to update then run **upgrade/deploy/cache** commands in sequence

I hope this will help you out let me know if any problem

Thanks

Comment: I've added all the above code apart from the `code`}
.main-container{
   z-index:5;
} where do I add this in? You are a star and I cannot thank you enough for helping me :)

Comment: I assume you have already extended your theme or using custom theme . app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_extend.less....... here in _extend.less you can write your custom less or css... after the run upgrade/deploy/cache commands

Comment: I've done it thank you so much. You have seriously made my day :)

Comment: Never mind ! My pleasure